# Understanding connection pools and authentication for a Postgres database in Node

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, connection-pooling

To start off with, I'm relatively new to the concept of querying Postgres databases from Node, as our main database is NoSQL. However, our analysis database is a Postgres database, which we are now going to call from our backend (hosted with Amazon's RDS service).

For the Postgres connection I use `node-postgres` ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg)), and for creation of authentication tokens I use Amazon's own SDK.

So what I do is the following: on the first request to the backend for which we need to query the Postgres db, I create a connection pool. As password in the `config` object in the `Pool` object initiation I use the authentication token generated by a `AWS.RDS.Signer` object (`signer.getAuthToken()`). This works fine for ~20 minutes (guessing the lifespan of the authentication token?), but throws an error for subsequent backend requests (*PAM Authentication failed for user <username>*).

I thought the whole point of a Postgres connection pool was to avoid having to re-authenticate once a new connection needed to be made - and to instead use one of the connections in the connection pool. If this is not the point of a connection pool, what is? Sorry for a potentially stupid question, but couldn't really wrap my head around this concept.

**Edit:** So this is basically how I've implemented it:

```
let pool
const connectToDb = async () => {
  const signer = new AWS.RDS.Signer({ ...signerConfig })
  const authToken = await signer.getAuthToken()
  pool = new Pool({ ...poolConfig, password: authToken })
  return pool
}

const queryWithPoolClient = async (queryString) => {
  const connectionPool = pool || await connectToDb()
  const client = connectionPool.connect() // crashes HERE!
  try {
    const res = client.query(queryString)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  } finally {
    client.release()
  }
}
```

Comment: @404 Thanks! Will update :)

Comment: please post your connection settings. It should work the way you mentioned.

Comment: Please see my latest edit

Comment: What about poolConfig? Where is it? Post it.

Comment: @IvanKolyhalov The poolConfig includes ssl (static path to a local SSL certificate), user/host/database (DB-related settings) and port. So nothing more than password in terms of authentication.